# Can be Implement comScore in Roku scene graph?

Tags: analytics, roku, brightscript, scenegraph, comscore

I want to implement comScore in Roku scene graph application. 
Is it possible/support to Roku scene graph application?
If possible, is SDK available for the scene graph?
Please provide suitable example that help to implement comScore in scene graph.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about ad measurements with comScore vCE?
if so, this is already handled by Roku's RAF library, all that's needed is to call [raf.enableAdMeasurements(true)](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Integrating+the+Roku+Advertising+Framework#IntegratingtheRokuAdvertisingFramework-enableAdMeasurements(enabled)) (+couple more methods mentioned in the doco) and to have comScore beacons in the ad XML